# error expected expression before '{' token (structures)

Tags: c, structure

declaring a book structure

```
struct book
{
char title[50];
char author[50];
int id;
};
```

even if I declare variables along with the definitions same error pops

```
void printbook(struct book b);

int main()
{
struct book b1={"48 laws of power","robert 
greene",286502}; /*indicating this line, it is saying error: expected 
expression before { token*/
printbook(b1);
return 0;
}

void printbook(struct book b)
{
printf("Book title=%s\n",b.title);
printf("Book author=%s\n",b.author);
printf("Book id=%d",b.id);
}
```

Comment: Do you really have a newline in the string? That's not allowed.

Comment: Please don't show images of errors or code. Copy-paste text (all text) as text. Please copy-paste the code *as is* in the IDE into the question and make sure that the formatting doesn't change.

Comment: And the asterisk in the window title bar means the file you show haven't been saved. What is the *actual* code you attempted to build?

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
struct book b1={"48 laws of power","robert 
greene",286502};
```

the string starting with `"robert` is not finished on the same line. Quoted strings may not be split across multiple lines.

You should join the two lines:

```
struct book b1={"48 laws of power","robert greene",286502};
```

Alternately, you can put a `\` as the last character of a line to cause it and the next line to be merged into a single line:

```
struct book b1={"48 laws of power","robert \
greene",286502};
```

On occasions where you do want a new-line character in a string (likely not this time), you can use `\n`:

```
struct book b1={"48 laws of power","robert \ngreene",286502};
```

Comment: If this (real) issue is the origin of the problem, the error message `expected expression before '{' token (structures)` is ultimately confusing :)

Comment: @chqrlie: Clang prints a warning that the string is not terminated, then an error that an expression is expected. OP may have reported only the error.

Comment: From the updated question, it seems the OP is not giving us complete information.